# boost::edge causing segfault

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to use the boost graph library, and I'm getting a segfault when I try to use boost::edge(). The full code is available [here](https://github.com/bgschiller/ninja-assassin-wonder-wall/blob/master/cpp_implementation/implication.cpp), but here I've made a minimal program that has the same issue (I'm compiling with "g++ minimal.cpp"):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

typedef adjacency_list<> graph_t;
typedef graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;

int main(){
    graph_t G;
    //add_edge(1,3,G);
    //remove_edge(1,3,G);
    pair<edge_descriptor, bool> res = edge(1,3,G);
    printf("G does %shave an edge 1->3\n", res.second ? "" : "not ");
    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment the add_edge, remove_edge lines, The segfault does not occur, and the program prints the expected

```
G does not have an edge 1->3
```

but is there a way to avoid such hackery? Thanks!

Comment: This looks a lot like a bug. You might want to bring it up on the [Boost-Devel Mailing List](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel) if you can't get a proper response on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `add_edge(1,3,G)` call adds vertices to the graph if needed. Your first call is in that case. Then it adds the edge from vertex 1 to vertex 3. Note that after this call, the number of vertices is 4, since the vertices are then indexed from 0 to 3.

The subsequent call to `remove_edge(1,3,G)` removes the edge that was just added, but leaves the number of vertices unchanged.

The call to `edge(1,3,G)` on the other hand does not add any vertex to the graph, the boolean in the return is there to state if vertices 1 and 3 are connected or not. There is an access violation is you remove the `add_edge` because the vertices at index 1 and 3 do not exist.

You can simply initialize the graph with the desired number of vertices:

```
graph_t G(4);
```

Comment: I appreciate the attention, but this was posted 6 months ago. I'm no longer actively working on this project. Also, it's not clear from the example above, but I think that it must be a bit more complicated than you're describing. I don't think calling add_edge(1,3,G) will add vertices 0 and 4.

Comment: Actually, I traced the instruction with the debugger, and was surprised myself to find "if (x >= num_vertices(g_))        g_.m_vertices.resize(x + 1);" (boost\graph\detail\adjacency_list.hpp, line 2186, boost 1.50)

Comment: Anyway, any question of this kind deserves an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. I was hesitant to accept your answer because it requires initializing the graph, but it sounds like even that happens implicitly anyway. Well done finding that!

Comment: The implementation seems strange to me. I would expect it to return .second=false if either of the vertices of the requested edge did not exist.